# BASH: use custom variable to update PATH

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I am trying to write a simple bash script that checks the output of command:`whereis ls` stores the relevant directory in a variable, in this case:

```
myvar=$(whereis ls | awk '{sub(/\/ls$/, "", $2); print $2}')
echo $myvar
$ /bin
```

Now using myvar I need to remove this directory from PATH and update PATH to reflect this change.
How can I most efficiently accomplish this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a pattern substitution `${parameter/pattern/string}` to update `PATH`:

```
PATH=${PATH/#$myvar:/:}
PATH=${PATH/%$myvar/:}
PATH=${PATH/:$myvar:/:}
```

For example:

```sh
$ echo $PATH
/bin:xxx:/bin:yyy:/usr/sbin:zzz:/bin

$ echo $myvar
/bin

PATH=${PATH/#$myvar:/:}   # remove $myvar at the beginning of $PATH
PATH=${PATH/%$myvar/:}    # remove $myvar at the end of $PATH
PATH=${PATH/:$myvar:/:}   # remove $myvar anywhere else in $PATH

$ echo $PATH
:xxx:yyy:/usr/sbin:zzz::
```

Alternatively you could use `sed`:

```sh
$ echo $PATH
/bin:xxx:/bin:yyy:/usr/sbin:zzz:/bin
$ PATH=$(sed -E "s@(:|^)$myvar(:|$)@:@g" <<< $PATH)
$ echo $PATH
:xxx:yyy:/usr/sbin:zzz:
```